# How to set/get number of displayed rows on ng-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, ngtable

The AngularJS `ng-table` offers a pagination functionality by default. On the bottom right there are buttons where the number of displayed records per page can be selected.

[image: Example for the pagination]

Is there a possibility to get the selected number and also set the number which is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After defining the parameters for the table:

```
var tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
    counts: [10, 20, 30, 50, 100],          // custom number of records options
    dataset: ...
});
```

You can get and set the number of records with the following code:

```
tableParams.count()   // get
tableParams.count(25) // set
```

---

**By the way:**
In the same way you can get and set the number of the current page:

```
tableParams.page()    // get
tableParams.page(2)   // set
```

Comment: so helpfull ....